# How to add the current page number in a cell of a calc sheet

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, page-numbers

I would like to add the current page number in a cell of that page and to refer back this cell for this page number in a cell somewhere in the same sheet / in another sheet. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this isn't possible - see [this FAQ on OpenOffice.org](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Formatting/How_do_I_insert_a_page_number_in_the_form_of_%27Page_1_of_N%27_on_each_page_of_a_spreadsheet?): Fields are only available in Header/Footer. There are [Spreadsheet functions](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Spreadsheet_functions), you they don't offer a function to access the "Page" value, only the number of the current [**`SHEET`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SHEET_function).